# Countdown timer in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, timer

Is it possible to create a countdown timer in C++ (any ver.),

> WHILE we are interacting on the output screen.

for example: A game is being played and we have to stop it after some given time.

I can create the timer either by using clock function or loop, but then, while the timer runs of course, I can't do anything.

So I want something like, a game being played and timer running in background, and the game ends, as the time is over.

Comment: You know about the [date and time functionality in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)? Have you tried to use them? How?

Comment: Put the check and the stop in some place which the game necessarily evaluates on a regular basis, like a screen refresh or physics update or event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quite simple answer to your question...
... multithreading!!!
It allows you to run processes parallel.
Little example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void threadfunction(){
  //Timer stuff here
}
int main()
{
  thread t1(threadfunction);
  // your game here
  t1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

I haven't tried the code yet because I hadn't the time, but I think it should work.

You could change a global variable if the time is elapsed to stop the game.

Hope this was helpful.